# Shell script/commands for text manipulation

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell script for formatting output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259293/shell-script-for-formatting-output)

I have a jacl script that spits out the text below, I want it better formatted.How can I achieve this ?

```
Stats for Cell=CELL Node=N01 Server=APP at 15:48:06
Stats name=WebContainer, type=threadPoolModule
name=PoolSize, ID=4, description=The average number of threads in a pool., unit=N/A, type=BoundedRangeStatistic, lowWaterMark=1, highWaterMark=50, current=4, integral=9.16145228E8, lowerBound=50, upperBound=50
Stats name=ORB.thread.pool, type=threadPoolModule
name=PoolSize, ID=4, description=The average number of threads in a pool., unit=N/A, type=BoundedRangeStatistic, lowWaterMark=1, highWaterMark=10, current=1, integral=1.26898089E8, lowerBound=10, upperBound=50
Stats name=WorkManager.BPENavigationWorkManager, type=threadPoolModule
name=PoolSize, ID=4, description=The average number of threads in a pool., unit=N/A, type=BoundedRangeStatistic, lowWaterMark=1, highWaterMark=10, current=5, integral=8.53089448E8, lowerBound=1, upperBound=5
Stats name=WorkManager.BPESchedulerWorkManager, type=threadPoolModule
name=PoolSize, ID=4, description=The average number of threads in a pool., unit=N/A, type=BoundedRangeStatistic, lowWaterMark=1, highWaterMark=1, current=0, integral=0.0, lowerBound=1, upperBound=5Scrits commands to convert the above to below.(Awk or sed ?)
```

How I would like to see the output.

```
CELL:N01:APP at 15:48:06
WebContainer threadPool current=4
ORB.thread.pool threadPool current=1
WorkManager.BPENavigationWorkManager threadPool current=5
WorkManager.BPESchedulerWorkManager threadPool current=0
```

Comment: Please read http://whathaveyoutried.com/ and try posing your question again.

Comment: Looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259293/shell-script-for-formatting-output

Comment: There are about a dozen different ways to get that output from your input but until you tell us WHY that's the output, we'd just be guessing. I mean are you pulling it out based on some text that surrounds it, or based on the position it has in the line or ....? Also are your lines wrapping above or does name=PoolSize really start on a line of it's own?

Comment: I want to see the output in a friendly format and remove repetitive entities

‘Stats’ is a new line.
‘name=’ is also a new line.

Answer (score 0):

For formatting, perl might be the way to go. You can use perl from commandline also. http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html

Although for your purposes I'd recommend writing a simple perlscript which looks something like

```
while(<>){
 chomp;
 $line = $_;
 $line =~ s/Stats for Cell=//;
 $line =~ s/ Node=/:/;
 ...etc
 print $line;
}
```